# Mocking gRPC status code ('RpcError' object has no attribute 'code') in Flask App

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, grpc, grpc-python

I have to create a unittest that should mock a specific grpc status code (in my case I need NOT_FOUND status).

This is what i want to mock:

```
 try:
    # my mocked function
 except grpc.RpcError as e:
        if e.code() == grpc.StatusCode.NOT_FOUND:
            # do something
```

My unittest until now looks like this:

```
def mock_function_which_raise_RpcError():
    e = grpc.RpcError(grpc.StatusCode.NOT_FOUND)
    raise e


class MyTestCase(BaseViewTestCase):
   @property
   def base_url(self):
      return '/myurl'

   @mock.patch('my_func', mock_function_which_raise_RpcError)
   def test_service_config_with_grpc_status_error(self):
       # some code

       assert resp.status_code == 404
```

First thing first, when I run my flask app and make a request to a URL with a specific body which should raise that RpcError, everything works just fine. `e.code()` is recognized. On the other hand, when i want to run that unittest, I get  `AttributeError: 'RpcError' object has no attribute 'code'`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you checked if your mocked function is being called?

Comment: @rdas yes, it is called. I think that the problem is at the way i mock the RpcError StatusCode...

Comment: I meant is the `mock_function_which_raise_RpcError` function called?

Comment: Yes. Is called.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you cannot construct a valid `RpcError` object from Python the same way it is created in the `grpc` code (which is written in C). You can, however, emulate the behavior by using:

```
def mock_function_which_raise_RpcError():
    e = grpc.RpcError()
    e.code = lambda: grpc.StatusCode.NOT_FOUND
    raise e
```

Alternatively, you can derive your own exception:

```
class MyRpcError(grpc.RpcError):
    def __init__(self, code):
        self._code = code

    def code(self):
        return self._code

def mock_function_which_raise_RpcError():
    raise MyRpcError(grpc.StatusCode.NOT_FOUND)
```

*Update:*
Added missing `code` method as mentioned by Martin Grůber in the comments.

Comment: Regarding the "own exception" solution, it actually must define a method as:
`def code(self): return self._code`. The `MyRpcError.code` is expected to be a callable.