# Mocking the method of Exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

I have the following code need to test:

```
def methodToTest(self, context):
    try:
         someRpcMethod() # <------ raise RpcError
    except RpcError as e:
         context.set_code(e.code())
         context.set_details(e.details())

#Test case
def test_methodToTest(self, someMockObject):
    someMockObject.someRpcMethod.side_effect = RpcError
    methodToTest()
```

when run the test, it says:

```
context.set_code(err.code())

AttributeError: 'RpcError' object has no attribute 'code'
```

how to mock the `code()` and `details()` for the testing?

Comment: How did you import `someRpcMethod` function?

Comment: Looks like the the same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61726226/12480730).