# how to create skeleton rpc error for pytest

Tags: pytest, grpc, grpc-python

so, I'm paching a method in pytest and I want to it to return rpc error with custom status code and message. I tried

```
my_error = grpc.RpcError()
my_error.code = ???
my_error.details = ???
```

so, there's no constructor for RpcError, so, I was wondering how do I set custom status code and message for mocking purposes. Is this doable?

so, in the code I'm testing, I have something like

```
except grpc.RpcError as e:
  print(e)
```

I want to see if the printed exception will be of certain format, and I'm only concerned with the status code and error details as of this moment.

Thanks

Comment: can’t you use mocks instead and have the RPCError be passed in as a spec?

Comment: @gold_cy I'm not sure how to do this, could you show sample code? thanks

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61726226/mocking-grpc-status-code-rpcerror-object-has-no-attribute-code-in-flask-ap